# Nuxt.js and Vue-i18next: Error: Cannot resolve "vue-i18next"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt.js application, I want to use [vue-i18next](https://github.com/panter/vue-i18next) so I installed it by [running](https://panter.github.io/vue-i18next/guide/started.html#requirements):

```
npm install @panter/vue-i18next
```

In the **nuxt.config.js** file, I declared it as per [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/);

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    vendor: ['vue-i18next']
  }
}
```

When I launch the server (`npm run dev`) I get this error message:

```
 ERROR  Nuxt error

  Error: Cannot resolve "vue-i18next" from "/home/begueradj/begueradj/vue-i18next"

  - nuxt.js:220 Nuxt.resolvePath
    [begueradj]/[nuxt]/lib/core/nuxt.js:220:11

  - module.js:121 ModuleContainer.addModule
    [begueradj]/[nuxt]/lib/core/module.js:121:35

  - utils.js:96 promise.then
    [begueradj]/[nuxt]/lib/common/utils.js:96:43


  - next_tick.js:189 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7

  - module.js:696 Function.Module.runMain
    module.js:696:11

  - bootstrap_node.js:204 startup
    bootstrap_node.js:204:16

  - bootstrap_node.js:625 
    bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

How to fix this? What is the reason behind this error?

Answer (score 1):

the `vendor` array is not used to import `plugins`.

create your own plugin in `plugins/` folder, and declare it in your Nuxt config:

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    plugins: ['~/plugins/vue-i18next']
  }
}
```

---

Another way is to used the nuxt community module: https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n